# ionic 4 populate list with button click

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic4

I have a page which generate list from array. I got the this example from the net. Which show html code output key one and key 2. (1) I would like to modify the code to output Key one only. How can I modify the code to do that ? (2) If I want to use button click to output just key one or key two, how can I do that? Here is the code :

```
messages = [{
    'One' : [
    {'id' : 1},
    {'id' : 2},
    ],
   'Two' : [
    {'id' : 1},
    {'id' : 2},
   ]
 }] ;


 @Component({
 ...
 })
 export class YourComponent{
 objectKeys: any = Object.keys;
 messages: Array<any>;

 out(key){

 }
 constructor(){}

 ...
 }


HTML:
<ion-button (click)="out('one')">button 1 </ion-button>
<ion-button (click)="out('two')">button 2 </ion-button>


<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
  <div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(message)">
    <div>KEY: {{ key }}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let val of message[key]">{{ val.id }}</div>
</div>
```

```
OUTPUT:
 KEY: One
      1
      2
 KEY: Two
      1
      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with solution (1) & (2) by using ng-if and ng-model Here is the code :

```
  html :
  <ion-button (click)="out('one')">button 1 </ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="out('two')">button 2 </ion-button>

  <ion-input type="hidden" [(ngModel)] ='nameFilter' ></ion-input>
  <div *ngFor="let message of messages"> 
  <div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(message)">
     <div *ngIf="key==nameFilter ">
        <div>KEY: {{ key }}</div>
        <div *ngFor="let val of message[key]">{{ val.id }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

ts code :

 @Component({
 ...
 })
 export class YourComponent{
 objectKeys: any = Object.keys;
 messages: Array<any>;
 nameFilter: String = 'one';

 out(key){
   if (key == 'one') {
      nameFilter = 'one';
   }
   else {
      nameFilter = 'two';
   }
 }
 constructor(){}

 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for (1) by using ngIf in the html code. Here is the working code :

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages"> 
   <div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(message)">
   <div *ngIf="key=='One' ">
       <div>KEY: {{ key }}</div>
       <div *ngFor="let val of message[key]">{{ val.id }}</div>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```